# How much do elevators deflect on takeoff?

Tags: aerodynamics, airliner, takeoff, elevator

Do elevators create immediate lift off on the big airplanes? E.g., on a 737, 747, or an Airbus, I don't see elevators moving up when I see airplanes lifting off in videos. Is it just a slight up movement that is hard to see then?

In other words—for airliners—how big of an elevator deflection is required for takeoff?

Comment: What do you mean by "immediate lift off"? You don't need a lot of elevator to make the aircraft pitch up for take-off, and usually once you get the nose up the elevator is pitched back down to level to maintain the climb.

Comment: I think perhaps the question is due to the fact that large aircraft have considerable momentum, and there is a delay in applying down elevator and the aircraft rotating to the required angle of attack to begin climbing.

Comment: To be more clear I mean what creates the sudden increae of angle of attack as a airplane lifts of the runway which looks like 45 degrees angle-- not immediate lift off. I can only conclude it is the elevators, however, on large airplanes eg 747, I do not see the elevators moving at  on take off in some lift off videos on You Tube.

Comment: There is no sudden increase in angle of attack, it's all very gradual. It takes time to rotate to the angle at which take-off occurs, hence why the elevator is not moving at the point of take-off.

Comment: Here is another way of saying it --  The airplane speeds up  on the runway -- it is horizontal -- then it suddenly goes into a 45 degree angle of attack lift off. Yet the elevators did not seem to move at all...

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. So to keep this simple, it is the elevators in up position that in fact create the 12 degree lift off in the larger airplanes --eg 747, airbus.

Comment: Next question is how much do the elevators deflect to create a 12 degree lift off in inches please.